# Function testing if array is Geometric not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to test an array to return a string 'Geometric' if it's Geometric and -1 if it's not. It's only returning - 1. I feel that my function makes sense. Any ideas?

```
var isGeometric = function(arr) {
    let format;
    let interval = arr[1] / arr[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        format = (arr[i] * interval === arr[i + 1])? 'Geometric' : - 1;
    }
    return format;
}

isGeometric([3,9,27]);
//returns -1, should return 'Geometric';


// Geometric array example = [3,9,27] or [5,25,125];
// each step in the array is multiplied by the same #;
```

Comment: What is "geometric" defined as? And your loop throws away all `format` results except for the last. Did you want to have an early return in there?

Comment: Can you post your arr ,how does it look?

Comment: There are a few things I can see that might cause issues. In the line where you are setting format you are doing a multiplication and checking for equivalence at the same time. For clarity you might want to wrap the multiplication in parentheses. Separately, you are resetting format on every loop. Is this what you want? When the loop is zero you set format and then when it comes over to 1 you are resetting the value. This might not be what you want it to return. Currently only the last loop will set the format variable.

Comment: kevin is talking about a function to check or geometric series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var isGeometric = function(arr) {
  let format;
  let interval = arr[1] / arr[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    format = (arr[i] * interval === arr[i + 1])? 'Geometric' : - 1;
    if (format === -1) break;
  }
  return format;
}
```

i hope it helped :)

the problems i fixed are:

1. your loop was going beyond the array size, i limited it
2. on each iteration, you were reseting format, i added a break statement, since one example is enough to prove it wrong

Comment: You should add some notes to explain what you've done otherwise it's pretty useless as an answer.

Comment: @Andy thanks, i made the changes, but i think there are some formatting problems in my phone

Comment: Yes! thanks, it appears to be working correctly now. Thank you!

Comment: thanx trincot and andy

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need a more detailed answer, read this.

```js
var isGeometric = function(arr) {

  const interval = arr[1] / arr[0];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // For the sake of readability
    const a = arr[i];
    const b = arr[i + 1];

    // This is to check if `b` is still valid value
    // `b` is undefined when your loop reaches the last array element
    if (!b){
      // If `b` is undefined, and your loop reaches the last loop
      // that means there is nothing else to multiply with.
      // So stop the loop.
      if ((i + 1) === arr.length)
        break;
        
      // If `b` is undefined, and your loop is NOT at the last loop,
      // it means something is wrong with one of your value.
      // That means the array is not a geometric, so return -1;
      // One other possibility for `!b` === true is when `b === 0`.
      // In this case, that means it is not a geometry anyway.
      // So return -1 is also correct.
      else
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Return `-1` as soon as it is not a geometric.
    // If you keep looping, the result might change.
    // Besides, you have no reason to keep the loop if you already know it's not a geometric.
    if ((a * interval) !== b)
      return -1;
  }

  // If the above loop successfully finishes running,
  // there is only one reason: the array is a loop.
  // So, return 'Geometric'.
  return 'Geometric';
  
}


console.log(isGeometric([3, 9, 27]));
console.log(isGeometric([5, 25, 125]));
console.log(isGeometric([10, 100, 1000]));
console.log(isGeometric([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternate solution, it's very helpful seeing this process!